# IE11 caching breaking status page

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a status page that needs to be constantly refreshed.  It makes ajax calls to a Java server and gets the updated statuses.  It works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE11 it is not refreshing when I click refresh.  However, when I open the dev tools, it does work.  As soon as I close dev tools, it stops working.  I have the following meta tags in my head:

```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

And it won't be enough to set my own browser to not use caching; I need it to work for users without them having to change their browser settings.

Answer (score 2):

According to this, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/234067, there is a bug in IE around this. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/222064 explains it. Maybe you're hitting that? I would also say you should make sure your meta tags are at the top of the head section.

Alternatively, I think the best solution would be to use HTTP headers. I've had very good results with cache HTTP headers.

Comment: Looks like adding another head at the end of the doc is not working.  I will try the HTTP header option

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:  Apparently, IE caches ajax calls, so that needs to be disabled.  Adding 'cache: false' to the ajax call fixes the issue:

```
$.ajax({
    url: www.url.com,
    cache: false
})
```